# How can I return a lookup value from a third column from a reference value in two cells?

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with two sheets. I'm trying to reference one sheet's numbers based on text using a formula in the other sheet. I have one sheet that looks something like this -

[image: Sheet 1]

And another that looks like this -

[image: Sheet 2]

I would like to put a formula on the first sheet that basically says - look on the second sheet for the values in columns A and B and return me the value in column C. The tricky part is - the values in the first sheet may be inverted or there may be an instance where only one value is present, like in row 1 in the first sheet. Also the formula should only fill in a value if both columns match. All text combinations in Sheet 2 are unique.

So for example - on the first sheet the formula should return 1 in cell C1, 5 in cell C4, and would error in the other 2 cells.

I hope that wasn't too confusing. I would greatly appreciate any help you can give.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible typo - I think you meant "5 in cell _C4_".

Comment: That is what I meant, sorry about that. Thank you!

Comment: One question: should `bird | sky` return 3 or empty?

Comment: Yes it should, since there is no matching column.

Comment: @DanielSouza Scott's solution has "Sky | Bird" in `E3:F3`, while OP has `Bird` only... that's why the formula returns a 3 in the screenshot.

Comment: @BigBen thanks, I thought the second screenshot was the sheet he had values to lookup for, but Scott's answered has already the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two sumifs together:

```
=SUMIFS(G:G,E:E,IF(A1="","",A1),F:F,IF(B1="","",B1))+SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,IF(A1="","",A1),E:E,IF(B1="","",B1))
```

[image]

Comment: My apologies, the formula has to return the exact value of whatever is in column C, it can't be a SUM function. I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough there. I appreciate your response!

Comment: This assumes that the values in E:F are unique.  If the combinations are unique it will not matter.

Comment: Oh! I apologize, this worked perfectly! Thank you so much!